# How to convert date time to date by removing time in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datetime

In SQL Server, I have two date columns which are declared as

```
CAST(FROM_Datevalue AS DATE) AS [FROM],
CAST(TO_Datevalue AS  DATE) AS [TO]
```

and in my proxy stub I am declaring two nullable datetime fields:

```
public DateTime? From { get; set;} 
public DateTime? To { get; set; }
```

In my controller, I use this code:

```
if (!(From).IsStringNullOrEmpty())
    parameters.Add("START_DATE", From);

if (!(To).IsStringNullOrEmpty())
    parameters.Add("END_DATE", To);
```

I need to get only date in MM/DD/YYYY format, but I am getting mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss

I tried `datetime.parse`, `convert.todatetime` but none of them are working

Comment: `From.Date` gives you a datetime without time. There's really no concept in .NET of a Date, only DateTime.

Comment: but at present using above code i am getting date in mm/dd/yyyy format with 12:00:00 timestamp after exporting to excel but i need to get mm/dd/yyyy only

Comment: That's an excel issue. Just change the format of those cells to mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: A `DateTime` datatype doesn't have a format - it stored a `DateTime` its only formatted when displayed (or exported) which uses a default formatting based on the regional settings of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
FORMAT(FROM_Datevalue, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as [FROM]

FORMAT(FROM_Datevalue, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as [FROM]
```

Comment: Not recommended, while you can format the datetime in the database, you're better off keeping it in its native type until you need to format it.